# Why is force called the rate of change of momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum

Why is **force** called the *rate of change of momentum*?

If I push a wall I do exert a force but there is no movement; so is there force acting on the wall?

Comment: There is no movement because the wall pushes back with the exact same amount of force and there is no net force to accelerate anything. As to your first question: force is that which accelerates mass. That's just the definition of what force is. We get often sidetracked by forces that deform matter, which is used as a technical aid to measure an approximation of force (e.g. with a spring inside a force gauge), but that deformation is not the definition of force.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this shows lack of any research-effort. This type of question can be easily solved by quick googling. Both questions of OP are directly or indirectly answered by 1st & 2nd law, & thus is too trivial to be asked as a question here

Comment: @CuriousOne Forces have an actor and a subject. The fact that a wall pushes back with an equal and opposite force is not why it doesn't move (much). Two astronauts can push against each other in deep space and accelerate even though they feel equal and opposite forces. The wall doesn't move because other forces act on it. You could try pushing a smooth bottomed wall on a flat frictionless surface and see that.

Comment: @Timaeus: All physics is local. That things between "I" and "the wall" don't move is due to the absence of a net force. How "I" and "the wall" generate those forces is absolutely irrelevant.

Comment: @CuriousOne There are forces "on" you due to everything else (including the wall) and there are forces "on" the wall due to everything that isn't the wall (including you). It is the forces "on" you that determine your acceleration. And it is the forces "on" the wall that determine the wall's acceleration. Discussing a force the wall exerts on you does not explain why the wall doesn't accelerate. It does accelerate when you push on it unless other forces act on it too. For instance if you push yourself off the wall (say to get some speed for roller skating) that momentum comes from somewhere.

Comment: @Timaeus: I don't care about any other forces. I only care about the forces on the spot where my finger pushes the wall. Why does that spot not move? Because in that spot the total sum of all forces is zero. The world can come to an end in the rest of the universe, it still wouldn't matter for local physics.

Comment: @CuriousOne Forces aren't on spots, a force is a transfer of momentum between things that have momentum. If the wall doesn't change its momentum it is because the wall passed on an equal (not equal and opposite) momentum to a third party.

Comment: @Timaeus: Now you need either continuum mechanics or an ad-hoc rule to transport contact forces to the center of mass of an object (which we have). That unnecessarily complicates the local physics problem, though. In any case, there is no need to have any momentum transfers. You can have an extended system under tension where all forces in all points are in equilibrium and absolutely nothing moves. That doesn't mean there are no forces acting (otherwise boilers couldn't explode or we couldn't explain boiler explosions with forces).

Comment: @CuriousOne People can (wrongly) think that nothing ever accelerates because action-reaction force pairs "cancel" (rather than just conserving momentum by acting on different objects). The wall doesn't move very much only because other forces act on the wall too, not because acceleration never happens. I'm trying to document for future readers that your comment could mislead them.

Comment: @Timaeus: The DEFINITION of force equilibrium is that nothing moves. That does not eliminate forces, otherwise we wouldn't need civil engineers to properly size static structures. I did not mislead future readers. I clearly said that the definition of force is by acceleration of mass. That does not mean that forces can't act without acceleration.

Comment: @CuriousOne The definition of force is not ma. Newton's second law is not a definition. And the everyday feeling that a wall doesn't move is not the same as someone saying you are in static equilibrium. You could push a wall by pushing off it, no one said this was an equilibrium problem. The wall ONLY fails to move (much) because there are OTHER forces acting on the wall besides just you.

Comment: @Timaeus: Newton's second law is the only definition of force. If you have another, please give it to us now. I hope it doesn't involve a spring in a plastic tube?

Comment: @CuriousOne Forces are defined by force laws, such as Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation (which isn't about spheres but is about the distances between individual masses). The second law of motion is about the net effects of all the forces on a subject.

Comment: @Timaeus Newton's second law is partly definition, partly physics's law.

Comment: @Timaeus: You are a very smart guy. Seriously, you are. The things you said the other day about QM were great. Unfortunately, on this one you have to go back to basics.

Comment: @Shing No. Forces come from force laws, lots of force laws for lots of forces. The second law tells you what they do, so it allows you the experimentally confirm the predictions of the force laws relative to the assumption of the second law holding.

Comment: @Timaeus: Please grab a good textbook on classical mechanics. Please.

Comment: @CuriousOne, for all the tearing apart that I've seen you do on others for honest misunderstandings of physics, you've made a blunder.  You can never, ever, every use an action/reaction pair as an explanation as to why an object doesn't move.  Forces are interactions between objects, and the action reaction pairs act on different objects.  To say that the point of contact between two forces doesn't move is meaningless, there's not an _object_ there!

Comment: @Sean: I am not using an action-reaction pair. Instead, I am inserting a small test mass at the contact point of two forces. This is perfectly allowed and if the forces are in equilibrium, then they will not accelerate the test mass. It also removes any ambiguity as to which forces we are talking about (I don't have to care about reaction forces). Neither do I have to care about whether the force is acting on the center of mass of any real mass (by definition of the size of the test mass it does). This is not the case if you wanted to analyze the movement of the wall.

Comment: @Sean: So why would you want to do this? To keep physics local. In high school physics we are doing a bit of a dance around the problem that what we really have is extended solids that are perfectly rigid and that have infinite speed of sound. This makes physics automatically non-local, which is a bad idea IMHO. You can work around that problem by inserting a measurement at the contact point of contact forces and then you use Newton's second law at that point as a definition for force (if it doesn't accelerate a test mass, then it's zero). Physically that is what really happens in continua.

Answer (score 1):

According to Newtonian mechanics, the state of rest or uniform motion is changed due to applied forces. for instance let me consider i am standing at a place for more than hour, my foot becomes painful though i never applied any force on the floor or floor is exerting some force on me.

If you apply some force on a particle, then the work done by the force will result in change of motion causing a displacement along the same direction of applied forces. Now coming to your question let me assume that you keep on exerting the force on the wall for prolong time, but this results nothing so, ultimately there is no work done. finally you became tired by applying force on the wall.

If the applied force is more in magnitude comparing to the object than only it results in motion or displacement, work done on a particle will explain the change in force along the direction of displacement.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is force change in momentum?

It isn't. The proper sentence would be "*Why is **the sum of** forces rate of change in momentum?*".

We don't write $\vec F=d\vec p/dt$, we write:

$$\sum\vec F=\frac{d\vec p}{dt}$$

(*Note, as another answer says, we are not talking about simply **change of momentum** $dp$ but rather **rate of change of momentum** $dp/dt$, and I assume that that's what you mean.*)

This is Newton's 2nd law. Notice the summation sign $\sum$. One force doesn't imply momentum change necessarily. Your wall example is a good example. Or simply a book lying on a table. Force is exerted to hold up the book, but no momentum change happens.

If there is *a net force* - that is, if the *sum of forces* is not zero - then you *do* have a momentum change according to Newton's 2nd law.

Answer (score 0):

Force is defined as the rate of change of momentum, not change of momentum:

$F=\frac{dp}{dt}$

An impulse, $J$, defined as the integral of the product of force and the time during which it acts, however, causes a change in momentum:

$J=\int Ft\;dt =\Delta p$

Interestingly, in Isaac Newton's [Principia Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophi%C3%A6_Naturalis_Principia_Mathematica), Newton originally stated the [Second Law of Motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_2nd_Law) in the impulse format, not in terms of an instantaneous force.

When you push on a wall, you exert a force on it, but you don't notice the effect due to its support; other forces are acting on it which cancels your force. Remember, the effect of exerting multiple forces on a single object depends on the vector sum of the forces, not due to a single force.